# Why does strftime('%G', strtotime('2017-01-01')) produce 2016?

Tags: php, strftime

I found a possible bug in PHP 5.6. The function `strftime` with a parameter of `%G` generates the 4 digit year. However, it seems to return the wrong year when fed `1483246800` - i.e. Jan 1, 2017. It returns 2016 instead!

Example code snippet:

```
echo strftime('%G', strtotime('2017-01-01'));
```

This should print "2017", but I get "2016" instead. I am running PHP 5.6. 
This edge case also shows up for other years - e.g. 2016-01-03 outputs 2015 instead of 2016.

Comment: What is your locale?

Comment: This goes by ISO weeks that start on a Monday, so Jan 1 2017 is a Sunday that is in the week that started Monday Dec 26 2016.  Maybe you want to use `Y` instead.

Answer (score 9):

It's not a bug.

As [someone pointed out](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21212) in answer to a bug report someone else filed a while back:

> %G - The 4-digit year corresponding to the ISO week number (see %V). This has the same format and value as %Y, except that **if the ISO week number belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead**...A reminder about ISO week numbers. They begin on mondays, end on sundays, and are **considered a part of the year in which the majority of their days fall**.

This means that using `%G` for a date close to a year's beginning/end could give you the correct year, the **previous** year, as in your case, or the **next** year, (for example, `echo strftime('%Y', strtotime('2002-12-30))` gives `2003`).

If you want to get the correct year, you should use `%Y` instead. `echo strftime('%Y', strtotime('2017-01-01'));` gives 2017.

It's also worth checking out [the definition of %V](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

> ISO-8601:1988 week number of the given year, starting with the first week of the year with at least 4 weekdays, with Monday being the start of the week.

Comment: It makes a hell lot's of sense now, So technicly if the op was to put `echo strftime('%G', strtotime('2017-01-02'));` he would get 2017 ?