# PHP: strftime() vs. last day of year

Tags: php, strftime

strftime() formats the year for last day of current year incorrect.
The following returns "31. Dezember 2019":

```
strftime('%d. %B %G',strtotime('31 December 2018'))
```

The behaviour is reproduceable on several servers.
date() resolves correct but is no option due to setlocale()

Any ideas?

Comment: use "new DateTime()" object :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does strftime('%G', strtotime('2017-01-01')) produce 2016?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513143/why-does-strftimeg-strtotime2017-01-01-produce-2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%Y` instead of `%G` if you don’t want to deal with ISO-8601:1988

As per this specification week №1 is the first week (beginning with Monday) including Thursday in January so 2018-12-31 is part of this week (2019-01-03 is Thursday).

As such `%G` is returning `2019`.

> **`%G`**
>
> The full four-digit version of [the year going by ISO-8601:1988 standards]

Answer (score 1):

`%G` will represent 4 digit version of `%g` (*Two digit representation of the year going by ISO-8601:1988 standards (see %V)*).

`%V` - *ISO-8601:1988 week number of the given year, starting with the first week of the year with at least 4 weekdays, with Monday being the start of the week*

Try `%Y` instead.

[DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

[DEMO](https://eval.in/1061743)

Answer (score 0):

It's a `setlocale` issue. Dezember is correct in Germany so i guess your server is in Europe/Berlin. Try to rewrite it like this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); //for Netherlands just an example
```

According to `strftime` documentation :

> Format the time and/or date according to locale settings. Month and
>   weekday names and other language-dependent strings respect the current
>   locale set with setlocale().